# Squid conditional selection of parent proxy

Tags: proxy, conditional-statements, squid

Is there a way to configure the Squid proxy server in order to make it select a different parent proxy (specified by the `cache_peer` directive) based on the hostname in the requested URL, say in the outgoing HTTP(S) request?

For example, if the requested URL contains `*.example1.com` then select `proxy1.host`. If it contains `*.example2.com` and `*.example3.com` then select `proxy2.host`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes

the directives you'll need are

```
acl example1 dstdomain example1
acl example2 dstdomain example2
cache_peer proxy1.host parent 3128 0 no-query default
cache_peer proxy2.host parent 3128 0 no-query default
cache_peer_access proxy1.host allow example1
cache_peer_access proxy2.host allow example2
```

You might also want to know how these directives work

```
never_direct
always_direct
```